# Windsor - The Hour - Bottom Bracket Dimensions

Tags: bottom-bracket

I'm looking to replace the bottom bracket in my Windsor "The Hour" since I'm buying  a new crank set for my bike.  What are the dimensions for the bottom bracket: both shell width and shaft length?  I can take the bottom bracket out to measure it, but I would rather only do it once while installing the new parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In http://www.bikesdirect.com/products/windsor/thehour.htm it says:

```
Sealed Cartridge 103mm
```

Trying to find shell widths for 103mm sealed cartridges only gives 68mm as the only possible combo for 103mm the length. e.g http://sheldonbrown.com/harris/bottombrackets.html

So it should be `68m x 103mm`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that.  I was just so stuck in googling, "windsor hour bb" and such so much so that I didn't even think on looking up typical bracket standards.